# cURL Response Content Type on Fedora

Tags: php, apache, curl

Hi I am trying to execute a cURL request, now the problem is that the same request works fine on my internal WAMP server based on Windows 8.1 OS that I use for development but is creating problems when I run it on my actual web server that is based on Fedora OS.

Here is the cURL that I am trying to execute:-

```
$service_url = 'https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/ers/artifact/82aabfb71bd6a468/30819/0';

        $curl = curl_init(); // Create REST Request
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $inUsername . ':' . $inPassword);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept:application/pdf', 'Accept-Language:en-CA'));
        $curl_response = curl_exec($curl); // Execute REST Request
        if(curl_errno($curl)){
            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl) . "\n";
        }

        echo 'HTTP Response Status: ' . curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) . "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>" . $curl_response . "<br/>";
```

Now the problem is that this same code returns a proper PDF response when I run it on my internal server and I get a HTTP Response Status: 200.

But when I run this same code in Fedora it returns HTTP Response Status: 202 and the actual response content i.e. "$curl_response" is blank.

I tested the URL in FireFox "REST Client" extension and it works fine returning a HTTP Response Status: 200 even Chrome "Advanced Rest Client" App works fine returning HTTP Response Status: 200. "$curl_response" has the PDF content all the time except when the code runs on Fedora.

It seems that the code is not working only on Fedora, so can anyone give me any suggestions as to what might be wrong over here.

Thanks in advance.

PS:- Okay I just tried something, I am beginning to feel that the cURL request when run on Fedora is not waiting for a response, it is running like in Asynchronous mode.

Okay this is how the logic works, I execute function A which returns me a value that I store in the variable "$service_url". Then I use this variable as the url for the cURL request(SEE THE CODE). But then I get a HTTP Status Response : 202, but after sometime if I hard code the "$service_url" value to the previous URL which created the error then it works fine even on Fedora.

Here's a test run

```
Test 1:-
->Executed function A()
->automated value "sampleURL" get's stored in variable "$service_url"
->Use "$service_url" as the url for cURL and execute it
->HTTP Status Response 202
->cURL content is blank





Test 2:-(After waiting sometime)
->Run the same script but this time I hardcode variable $service_url = "sampleURL";
->Use "$service_url" as the url for cURL and execute it
->HTTP Status Response 200
->cURL content is PDF content
```

I feel that maybe cURL is not waiting for a response and returns immediately like making an async request rather than making a sync request.

Here's the Header output:-

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted Server: Oracle-iPlanet-Web-Server/7.0 
Date: Tue, 21 Jan 2014 20:27:58 GMT 
X-backside-transport: OK OK 
Transfer-encoding: chunked 
Set-cookie: CPO_SSID_PRD32_BL_CT_ERS=R332319479; path=/ 
Svn-build-number: ShippingTools.buildLevel.20140111.MR1_2014-B3838.3838 
Content-type: application/octet-stream 
HTTP Response Status: 202
```

Comment: Hm, `202`: _"The entity returned with this response SHOULD include an indication of the request's current status and either a pointer to a status monitor or some estimate of when the user can expect the request to be fulfilled."_ Maybe the reason is in the response headers, have you checked those & what are they? Also, I've seen some issues with user-agent sniffing, you could try to set a random user agent header in your request to see if that solves is, or the a specific one you know to work from your other attempts.

Comment: I'll try setting the User Agent

Comment: Okay setting User Agent in the cURL request didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, assumed as much when I saw your `PS`. What's the entire output if you use `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` (output will go the `STDERR`, unless you send it elsewhere using `CURLOPT_STDERR`)? Also, do you have a `.curlrc` file anywhere?

Comment: sorry but what is ".curlrc" file, I don't know anything about this file

Comment: Save that for later. I see some response headers, but I see no request headers, what are they?

Comment: that is the header output that get's returned, along with the curl response, I set the CURLOPT_HEADER to true

Comment: Okay I just made the script sleep for like 10 secs before executing the cURL and it worked

Comment: If you truely set the `VERBOSE` option... You'd see request headers AFAIK... If this doesn't work for you, set `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` & use `curl_getinfo()` to see them.

Comment: I'll try doing that tomorrow, it's 02:30 AM over here and many thanks for your suggestions, I will test it and let you know what happened